# How to Dotnet Publish from VSTS with Private Linux Hosted Build Agent?

Tags: .net, amazon-ec2, .net-core, azure-devops

Scenario - 
 I am trying to build and deploy project based on ASP.Net core2.0 on Ubuntu ec2 instance.

From VSTS -  
 I have created a Linux Private Build Agent on VSTS account.

Installing Linux Build Agent -  
I have installed dotnet core 2.1.3 
Also, successfully registered the Linux Private Agent on ec2.

Now,  
From VSTS - Build and Release Tab-  
Build Defination I have following tasks -

1) dotnet restore - This task gets executed successfully.

## [image: dotnet restore image]

## 2) dotnet build  - This task gets executed successfully. 
[image: dotnet build image]

## 3) dotnet test - This task gets executed successfully. 
 [image: dotnet test image]

## 4) dotnet publish - This task creates published files for my all projects with .csproj. 
 [image: publish task image]

## 5) publish build artifact task [image: publish artifact task]

At the Task step 4, that means dotnet publish step- It publishes the published files at a path on Ubuntu private hosted agent ec2. For example, the path at which it publishes can be - 
ubuntu@ip-111-11-1-111:/agent/_work/1/a  
[image: linux build agent artifact folder] 
If you have noticed in the "dotnet publish" task that, I am specifying the perticular .csproj file, still in the artifact "a" folder on linux build agent, it is publishing all source projects.
Also, note that I have some errors during this task, so I can only post the screen of "a" folder with this incomplete output. 
For more information, I am also posting the screen for details from source "s" folder on build agent. 
[image: linux build agent -source folder] 
Please let me know, how can I publish only the particular project/source folder from VSTS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **publish** instead of custom in your step 4 (.NET Core task Command option):

[image]

**Note:** you should deselect Publish Web Projects option in .NET Core publish task.

For the reason why your step 4 published all the projects, it’s caused 
 the option `publishWebProjects` set as `true` by default and the option can not be changed if you use custom command in .NET Core task. So it actually search for `**/*.csproj` pattern and ignore the project you specified.